# How to check if a file already contains an object?

Tags: java, file, object, header

I am trying to add objects (people's names, phone numbers etc.) to a file and then reading it. When I run the program and add a few objects to the file, only the first object contains the header and the ones after the first one does not, which is what I want.

However, if I close the program and then rerun it, the previous objects are still there and functioning, but if I add a new object to the file, the program treats it as "the first object", so gives it a header, which causes an error when the program tries to read the information stored in the object.

This is my "add to file" code:

```
try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("outputfile.ser", true);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    }
    catch (NotSerializableException e1) {
        System.out.println("An object was not serializable, it has not been saved.");
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }


    JButton btnAddContact = new JButton("Add Contact");
    btnAddContact.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                Address newContact = new Address(firstNameTextField.getText(), lastNameTextField.getText(), homePhoneNumberTextField.getText(), mobilePhoneNumberTextField.getText(), addressTextArea.getText(), emailTextField.getText());

                try {
                    oos.writeObject(newContact);
                }
                catch (IOException e1) {
                    System.out.println("An object was not serializable, it has not been saved.");
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            dispose();
            firstNameTextField.setText("");
            lastNameTextField.setText("");
            homePhoneNumberTextField.setText("");
            mobilePhoneNumberTextField.setText("");
            addressTextArea.setText("");
            emailTextField.setText("");
        }
    });
    btnAddContact.setBounds(165, 384, 110, 46);
    contentPane.add(btnAddContact);
```

I also thought that if i checked if the file is empty or not using `if (file.length() == 0)` would work, but it still doesn't work. sample of my code with this implemented:

```
File file = new File("outputfile.ser");
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
ObjectOutputStream oas = AppendingObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file, true));
if (file.length() == 0){
                    try {
                        oos.writeObject(newContact);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println("An object was not serializable, it has not been saved.");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        oas.writeObject(newContact);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e1) {
                        System.out.println("An object was not serializable, it has not been saved.");
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

public class AppendingObjectOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {

    public AppendingObjectOutputStream(OutputStream oas) throws IOException {
        super(oas);
    }

    protected void writeStreamHeader() throws IOException {
        // do not write a header, but reset:
        reset();
    }
}
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your first `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);` will overwrite any existing file.

Try at first to change it `FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file, true);`.

But I discourage opening at the same time the same file. You probably need to rework the logic.

Comment: Thank you for your input and sorry for the late response (Had class all day). I will try what you have suggested! Is there any way of continuously adding objects to the file, even if the program is closed and then reopened? :)